# Adding rows to SharePoint 2013 Promoted Links

Tags: 2013

Could anyone provide more detail on how to span Promoted Links in SharePoint 2013 to display on multiple rows? I've looked at the following link that details the process, just have no idea what file(s) to edit.

http://jsypeksharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/09/adding-rows-to-sharepoint-2013s.html

Comment: I'm having some issues with this.. I have two pormoted links wep apps on the same page.. when I use the jquery, it does limit to the amount of icons. however, it makes one row of 5 then the rest adds to the second list.. any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange. Your reply is not an answer to the question, and may be removed. Please refer to the FAQ on how to answer. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you need to edit the page that you have the promoted links webpart on.  And then add a content editor webpart and add his javascript into the source of that webpart.  Make sure you've included a reference to jquery on your page.

Comment: The page that has the Promoted Links is the home page (ex. http://localhost). If I open the Home page in SharePoint Designer or click on the web part then click Edit List to open in SharePoint Designer, I'm not sure where to go from here. There is no file that I can find that displays the same HTML code listed on the link I referenced.

Comment: Just edit the page in the browser and add the content editor webpart.

Comment: I click Edit page, then add content editor web part in the same area as the Promoted Links. If I try to paste any code into the content editor web part it displays as rich text. Maybe if I find the Source Editor it would help. If I simply click Edit Source from the ribbon, I barely see any code. If I click Embed Code and paste code into that, it doesn't work either. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Download jquery from http://jquery.com/, download his script. Store both in a document library. Open the script, add a reference to jquery then wrap his script in script tags. Add the URL of the script to the Link to Content box of the content editor web part.

Answer (score 0):

This gentleman has written a javascript file that is used with the JSLink feature.

http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/08/11/display-promoted-links-multiple-lines/

Instructions are included in the article.

To create multiple lines just adjust the width of the webpart till you have the right number of rows you need (e.g. reduce the width to create more rows.).

I am using it and it works great!